# How to use wine with more security?

Tags: wine, malware, mingw32

This question may sound duplicate but please read. I am trying to make a cross compiled application. So I would like to try mingw64. But while installing it I found that it requires wine. I have heard that wine can be affected by virus and some viruses can affect my linux as well. How can I use it more securely? Is there a way I can contain wine while using it? Any trick or tips?

Answer (score 3):

Tl;dr don't run untrusted programs and you'll be fine

---

WINE isn't malware. WINE is a way to run Windows executables on Linux. So, if you only run programs you trust with WINE, it won't be an issue. If I had to guess, the place you read that really meant "If you download Windows malware and run it with WINE, that can harm your Ubuntu system". So, don't run untrusted programs with it.

Regarding what you're actually doing (corss-compiling for Windows), you won't need to run WINE directly. Just use the mingw cross compiler and you'll be good. You may want to use WINE to test your compiled program (although do note that WINE isn't perfect), but if you're just using it for your program and not running random executables with it, you'll be fine.

Comment: So you are saying if I don't try anything from external source I am safe?

Comment: @SohanArafat You don't *have* to refrain from using anything from an external source - if you stick to well-known, trustworthy external sources (like the 7-Zip official website), you should be fine. But yes, avoiding all external sources entirely will also keep you safe.

Comment: Another thing. If I find out there is a malicious virus how do I remove everything? Just to be safe.